# I'm failed to install r8723bs to Ubuntu16.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I am failed to install r8723bs to Ubuntu16.04 on Intel Compute Stick.

**What I did is...**

```
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic git
$ git clone https://github.com/hadess/rtl8723as.git
$ cd rtl8723as
$ make
$ sudo make install
$ sudo depmod -a
$ sudo modprobe r8723bs
```

But when I input "sudo modprobe r8723bs", terminal says

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module r8723bs not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-150-generic
```

How can I solve this issue?
Could you kindly tell me what should I do?

Comment: Did you put the module into the modprobe directory? Without that, the system isn't going to find it.

Comment: Hi, Nasir Riley. I did not it. How can I  put the module into the modprobe directory?

Comment: You need to put it in `lib/modules/$(uname -r)` as `root`. Afterwards, you'll be able to see it with `lsmod | grep <module-name>` and then load it with `modprobe`.

Comment: How can I put the module in `lib/modules/` as root?
Could you tell me step by step?

Answer (score 0):

I compiled a different version: rtl8812au

After compiling, I copied the `8812au.ko` file into: `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/net/wireless/` and then ran `depmod -a`. Yours will be named differently because it's a different version.

If you are in the directory where you compiled it, you'll see a file called `8723bs.ko` (or something similar). That's the module file that you need to load but you've skipped a step after compiling.

First, copy it to the proper modules directory:

```
cp 8723bs.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/
```

Next, run this command to map the module files:

```
depmod -a
```

Lastly, load the module file:

```
modprobe 8723bs
```

You'll then be able to see it loaded with this command:

```
lsmod | grep 8723bs
```